# How to track dynamic a vhost configuration that maps to folder structure?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

For development purposes we would like to access dynamic vhosts from the same computer (localhost, or better local loop) and from the LAN. This subdomain vhost should map to the given folder structure. Each folder represents one project. As I figured out this can be done with `%1`. Syntax check is ok (`apachectl -t` and `apachectl -S`). Also, the vhosts are caught by our local DNS server. That works perfect. But something is wrong with my Apache 2.4 vhost config. Please see below my `vhosts.conf`:

```
UseCanonicalName Off
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAlias alpham.dev
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName alpham.dev
        ServerAlias *.alpham.dev
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/vhosts/%1"
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit: When accessing e. g. example.alpham.dev, it should use the folder `Library/WebServer/vhosts/example`. But we get only a blank page. There are no `error_log` and no `access_log` entry for this. How to track this problem?

I followed the tutorial from [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/set-automatic-virtual-hosts-nginx-apache/)

Comment: You've used the same server name in both virtual hosts. That probably won't do what you want. Beyond that, you should actually describe the problem you're having.

Comment: Apache isn't very strong in debuggability...

Answer (score 0):

The above shown config works pretty fine. The problem is the Mac DNS Server. It does not resolve any subdomain (vhost) to the same ip as the domain itself. It does poorly nothing. Normally in the internet, if you bought a domain this works just fine. There was until now no need for me to configure it. Subdomains worked automatically for me.

In conclusion, this question is answered. I asked another question related to the mac dns server on [ask different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270311/how-to-dns-resolve-also-subdomains-to-same-host-as-the-domain-itself-using-wildc).